# How can I store reference of a class in the same type of class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, reference

I have a class Person and i want to store reference of another Person in that class but im getting the error : function "Person::operator=(const Person &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

in the function getThem()

```
class Person {
private:
    Person& them;
    int number;
public:
    Person giveYourself(){
        return *this;
    }
    int giveNumber(){
        return number;
    }
    void getThem(Person& they){
        them = they.giveYourself();
    }
};
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect the line `them = they.giveYourself();` to do? Recall that references cannot be rebound. Once you've decided which `Person` `them` is a reference to, you cannot later decide that it should be a reference to another `Person` object.

Comment: @NathanPierson Oh yes i forgot references cannot be rebound but what if i want to store another Object of the Same Class type in this class do i have to make a pointer for that??

Comment: @NathanPierson I wanted this class to store more person

Comment: Once a reference is initialised so it refers to an object, it cannot be reinitialised (made to refer to a different object).   Any operations on the reference (e.g. `ref = something`) act on the referred object, and don't change what the reference refers to - for the life of the reference.   If you want to change what the reference refers to, you need to use a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just answering this question, although I don't think it's a good idea to do things in your way. I believe what you need is `std::list<Person>` or something like this.

Let's get into the point. It's completely OK to contain a reference in class. But the problem is that, the auto-generated copy-assignment operator and move-assignment operator don't know how to deal with a reference. So you have to manually define it:

```
class Person {
private:
    Person& them;
    int number;
public:
    Person &operator=(const Person &another) {
        number = another.number;
        return *this;
    }

    Person giveYourself(){
        return *this;
    }
    int giveNumber(){
        return number;
    }
    void getThem(Person& they){
        them = they.giveYourself();
    }
};
```

And it compiles now.